# How to create custom choice field in Django?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I'm trying to create a form in which user fill in language,description and level of the language (intermediate, advanced...).

The language model:

```
class Language(models.Model):
    shortcut = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    first_level_price = models.FloatField() # Basic
    second_level_price = models.FloatField() # Intermediate
    third_level_price = models.FloatField() # Advanced

    def __str__(self):
        return self.shortcut+': '+self.name
```

For each language there exist three levels and prices (`first_level_price`,`second_level_price`,`third_level_price`).

Now, I want user to fill the form. One of the forms should be the level. User just would chose either 'Basic','Intermediate' or 'Advanced'. According to this choice, there would be the price counted.

So if `user` have chosen 'Basic', there would be price according to `first_level_price` of the language.

I've tried many ways but no one worked.

```
level = forms.ChoiceInput(choices=('Basic','Intermediate','Advanced'))
```

Comment: Can you explain for what are you going to use the price level??

Comment: @DhiaTN This will be a private web for translators. There are many languages, for each language there are free levels of translation (basic,intermediate,advanced). The price depends on language and level (not translator). So if somebody wants to buy advanced english translation, it is more expensive that basic english translation etc... Did I answer to your question or did you mean something else?

Comment: no i mean how you are going to use it in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your model like this:

```
class Language(models.Model):
    PRICE_CHOICES = (
            ('first_level_price', 'Basic'),
            ('second_level_price', 'Intermediate'),
            ('third_level_price', 'Advanced'),

        )

    first_level_price = models.FloatField() # Basic
    second_level_price = models.FloatField() # Intermediate
    third_level_price = models.FloatField() # Advanced

    shortcut = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    level = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=PRICE_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.shortcut+': '+self.name
```

Now you can just create a `ModelForm` using this Model and it should work the way you expect.

When an user selects `first_level_price` aka `Basic` membership, you can now grab the price from the `first_level_price` field.

Comment: I've tried your solution and it seems good. But there is a one problem. Each language has it's own prices for levels. So English could have 5 $ at basic level, Czech could have 3 $ at basic level etc. Now I can't set these prices in admin.

Comment: OK, then you can add those fields too. I am updating my answer.

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check now.

Comment: Thanks, nice. But there is one problem :) I'm little confused what to do now to have a form, where customer choose language and it's level.

Comment: You need to create a form with all the language options, usually found from `Language.objects.all()`

Answer (score 1):

The choices should a tuple of pairs. The first value in the pair is the data you get into your form instance, the second value of the pair is the displayed value in your template:

```
level = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(('basic', 'Basic'), 
                                   ('intermediate', 'Intermediate'), 
                                   ('advanced', 'Advanced')))
```

Check [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ChoiceField.choices) details about the `choices`.